# How to convert minutes to hours/minutes and add various time values together using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

There are a couple parts to this question. I am not opposed to using a jQuery plugin if anyone knows of one that will accomplish what I want done.

**Q1 - How do I convert minutes into hours and vise versa? For example how would I convert 90 minutes into 1 hour and 30 minutes. In the code below how would I get "totalMin" converted and displayed in "convertedHour" and "convertedMin"?**

HTML:

```
<span class="totalMin">90</span> Minutes

<span class="convertedHour">0</span> Hours
<span class="convertedMin">0</span> Minutes
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ExFBD

**Q2 - How would I add up a group of time slots? For example, How would I add 1 hour 30 mins, 2 hours 45 mins and 2 hour 15 mins together?**

HTML:

```
<span class="hour-1 hour">1</span> hour
<span class="min-1 min">30</span> min

<span class="hour-2 hour">2</span> hour
<span class="min-2 min">45</span> min

<span class="hour-3 hour">2</span> hour
<span class="min-3 min">15</span> min


<span class="totalHour">0</span> hour
<span class="totalMin">0</span> min
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DX9YA/

**Q3 - How would I take a time value (3 hours and 30 mins) and add it to a real time stamp such as 10:30 AM? How would I take AM vs PM into account?**

Comment: Thanks for the insight, Mark. I'm obviously asking for help with the code to do it.

Comment: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Q1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var totalMinutes = $('.totalMin').html();

    var hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);          
    var minutes = totalMinutes % 60;

    $('.convertedHour').html(hours);
    $('.convertedMin').html(minutes);    
});
```

Q2:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var minutes = 0;

    $('.min').each(function() {
        minutes = parseInt($(this).html()) + minutes;
    });

    var realmin = minutes % 60
    var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60)

    $('.hour').each(function() {
        hours = parseInt($(this).html()) + hours;
    });


    $('.totalHour').html(hours);
    $('.totalMin').html(realmin);    

});
```

Comment:  `const convert = (n) => \`0${n / 60 ^ 0}\`.slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + n % 60).slice(-2)`

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько works like a charm ! Don't know why but who cares ?! Thanks :)

Comment: Answer provided by @Илья Зеленько is at the same time concise, short and elegant.

Comment: @kernelpanic, it's more important for code to be readable/understandable, than concise

Answer (score 104):

In case you want to return a string in 00:00 format...

```
convertMinsToHrsMins: function (minutes) {
  var h = Math.floor(minutes / 60);
  var m = minutes % 60;
  h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h; 
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m; 
  return h + ':' + m;
}
```

Thanks for the up-votes. Here's a slightly tidier ES6 version :)

```
const convertMinsToHrsMins = (mins) => {
  let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let m = mins % 60;
  h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h; // (or alternatively) h = String(h).padStart(2, '0')
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m; // (or alternatively) m = String(m).padStart(2, '0')
  return `${h}:${m}`;
}
```

Comment: This is my favourite answer, since it addresses the "00:00" format

Comment: `const convert = (n) => \`0${n / 60 ^ 0}\`.slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + n % 60).slice(-2)`

Comment: It's just vanilla JavaScript @sam - I would be worried if it didn't :D

Comment: To the person who keeps suggesting an edit to use floor on `mins % 60` - mins will be an integer, so there's no need to floor this.

Answer (score 25):

The function below will take as input # of minutes and output time in the following format: Hours:minutes. 
I used Math.trunc(), which is a new method added in 2015. It returns the integral part of a number by removing any fractional digits.

```
function display(a){
  var hours = Math.trunc(a/60);
  var minutes = a % 60;
  console.log(hours +":"+ minutes);
}

display(120); //"2:0"
display(60); //"1:0:
display(100); //"1:40"
display(126); //"2:6"
display(45); //"0:45"
```

Comment: _..which is a new method added in 2015_ Instead **2015**, **version number** should be more clear and comfortable. Thank You.

Comment: Are there any uses for this format anywhere? Lacking that the consistent HH:MM format makes it fairly useless surely.

Comment: @Leonard -- The solution pertains to the question above. This function can be used to return hours and any leftover minutes if you are given minutes. There are plenty of other use cases but this is not the place to list out every usecase, just the one that applies to the question above.

Comment: @Leonard -- The question does not require HH:MM format; even if that was needed, there is an answer right above showing how to convert to HH:MM format.

Comment: @DanS. Returning without the context of what I was working on before it's now so obvious! I must have been blinded by my own mission at the time. Cheers Dan!

Comment:  `const format1 = (n) => \`${n / 60 ^ 0}:\` + n % 60` or `const format2 = (n) => \`0${n / 60 ^ 0}\`.slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + n % 60).slice(-2)`

Answer (score 11):

Very short code for transferring minutes in two formats!

```js
let format1 = (n) => `${n / 60 ^ 0}:` + n % 60

console.log(format1(135)) // "2:15"
console.log(format1(55)) // "0:55"

let format2 = (n) => `0${n / 60 ^ 0}`.slice(-2) + ':' + ('0' + n % 60).slice(-2)

console.log(format2(135)) // "02:15"
console.log(format2(5)) // "00:05"
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var timeConvert = function(n){
 var minutes = n%60
 var hours = (n - minutes) / 60
 console.log(hours + ":" + minutes)
}
timeConvert(65)
```

this will log 1:5 to the console. It is a short and simple solution that should be easy to understand and no jquery plugin is necessary...

Answer (score 5):

```
function parseMinutes(x) {
  hours = Math.floor(x / 60);
  minutes = x % 60;
}

function parseHours(H, M) {
  x = M + H * 60;
}
```

Comment: Just dumping a couple of lines of code into a textbox doesn't make it an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I took the liberty of modifying ConorLuddy's answer to address both 24 hour time and 12 hour time.

```
function minutesToHHMM (mins, twentyFour = false) {
  let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let m = mins % 60;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;

  if (twentyFour) {
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    return `${h}:${m}`;
  } else {
    let a = 'am';
    if (h >= 12) a = 'pm';
    if (h > 12) h = h - 12;
    return `${h}:${m} ${a}`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This code can be used with timezone

javascript:

```js
let minToHm = (m) => {
  let h = Math.floor(m / 60);
  h += (h < 0) ? 1 : 0;
  let m2 = Math.abs(m % 60);
  m2 = (m2 < 10) ? '0' + m2 : m2;
  return (h < 0 ? '' : '+') + h + ':' + m2;
}

console.log(minToHm(210)) // "+3:30"
console.log(minToHm(-210)) // "-3:30"
console.log(minToHm(0)) // "+0:00"
```

```
minToHm(210)
"+3:30"

minToHm(-210)
"-3:30"

minToHm(0)
"+0:00"
```

Comment: This code has multiple bugs and I don't suggest using it as is if you ever expect negative minutes with imperfect hours, or negative minutes at all. -120 minutes returns -1:00 (wrong). -160 returns +0:00 (wrong). -180 returns -2:00.
There are logical flaws in the flooring and lack of Math.abs in the increment. Several lines should be rewritten to make it accurate.

Answer (score 2):

As the above answer of ConnorLuddy can be slightly improved, there is a minor change to formula to convert minutes to `hours:mins` format

```js
const convertMinsToHrsMins = (mins) => {
  let h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  let m = Math.round(mins % 60);
  h = (h < 10) ? ('0' + h) : (h);
  m = (m < 10) ? ('0' + m) : (m);
  return `${h}:${m}`;
}
```

My theory is that we can not predict that `mins` value will always be an integer.
The added `Math.round` to function will correct the output.
For example: when the minutes=125.3245, the output will be 02:05 with this fix, and 02:05.3245000000000005 without the fix.

Hope that someone need this!

Comment: That's fair :) My example was working on the assumption that it'll be an integer, just to keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

Not a jquery plugin, but the [DateJS Library](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) appears to do what you require. The [Getting Started page](http://www.datejs.com/2007/11/27/getting-started-with-datejs/) has a number of examples.

Comment: Serious? It's not an answer to the problem! Why don't you show how to do with DateJS?

Answer (score 0):

Alternated to support older browsers.

```
function minutesToHHMM (mins, twentyFour) {
  var h = Math.floor(mins / 60);
  var m = mins % 60;
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;

  if (twentyFour === 'EU') {
    h = h < 10 ? '0' + h : h;
    return h+':'+m;
  } else {
    var a = 'am';
    if (h >= 12) a = 'pm';
    if (h > 12) h = h - 12;
    return h+':'+m+a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const minutesToHour = totalMinutes => {
  if (!totalMinutes) return `${0}m`;

  const hours = Math.floor(totalMinutes / 60);
  const minutes = totalMinutes % 60;

  const h = hours > 0 ? `${hours?.toFixed()}h` : '';
  const m = minutes > 0 ? ` ${minutes?.toFixed()}m` : '';

  return `${h} ${m}`;
};

console.log(minutesToHour(90))
```