# Hour to Minutes 00:00 to 00 javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to convert hours:minutes (00:00) to minutes 00 in Javascript.

I thought about doing it by using substr to get hour and minutes separately and then multiply the hours part by 60 and then add the minutes part.

Is there any other easy way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687723/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-minutes-and-add-various-time-values-together-usi

Comment: How are you getting your minutes. post your scipt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty easy with `split`:

```
var str = "04:17";
var parts = str.split(":");
var minutes = parseInt(parts[0], 10) * 60 + parseInt(parts[1], 10);
console.log(minutes); // 257 (four hours and seventeen minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

To split in hour and minute, you can use the [split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function on the String object:

```
"12:05".split(':');

--> ["12", "05"]
```

Then you need to convert the Strings in the array to integers with [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp):

```
var hours = parseInt("12", 10);
var minutes = parseInt("05", 10);
```

Then rest is simple calculation:

```
var total = hours * 60 + minutes;
```

Comment: I'd read the question again. You're not handling the hours correctly. *(Not my dv)*

Comment: Does split() works like array(), please elaborate the coding. Thanks!

Comment: @TJ: Topic starter changed the question!

Comment: @asgoth: Using `parseInt` without a radix, particularly when you know the string is frequently going to start with `0`, is a **very** bad idea. :-) Try [this](http://jsbin.com/ezamur/1) on Firefox, for instance, or IE.