# javascript - Google API converting duration

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Currently I am using a google API to calculate distance and duration, and this works brilliantly into a string, however i don't want to store this data as:

```
2 hours 10 mins
```

**is there an easy way to convert this format in minutes? (130)**

my logic would be extract the numbers from the string so the value equals 210, and then perform some mathematical calculation on this:

```
var dur = screen.LabourAllocation.Duration;
var dura = dur.match(/\d/g);
dura = dura.join("");
```

can anyone else suggest a better method than this? if not what calculation could i do to convert 210 to minutes (130)?

thanks for any help

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687723/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-minutes-and-add-various-time-values-together-usi

Comment: From [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro#elements) the API returns the duration as localized text and in seconds

Comment: converting time in hhmm to minutes `(3 * v + (v % 100) * 2) / 5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get all number parts, your regex only catch numbers one by one so you need `/\d+/g`, then simple math.

```
var dur = "2 hours 10 mins";
var dura = dur.match(/\d+/g); // take all "grouped" number
// dura ["2", "10"]

dura = dura[0] * 60 + (+dura[1]); 
// first one is hours , second one need to be converted to number
```