# Format IMPORTXML function output as time "h:mm"

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I have a function in Google Sheets that calculates the travel distance between two locations:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?&origins="& A20 & "&destinations=" & B20 & "&mode=driving&key=mykey"; "//duration/text")
```

This works and the value in the cell is formatted as `4 hours 33 mins`.

How would I format it as `4:33`?

Comment: API key in edit history is invalid.

Comment: Use regex replace/extract?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - Google API converting duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452807/javascript-google-api-converting-duration)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your formula (assumed to be in A1) as below:

```
=substitute(substitute(A1," hours ",":")," mins",)
```