# How to convert minutes to hours and minutes in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am taking value in minutes and converting in hours its coming but for hours and minutes not coming proper value .

// if time is 120 its coming 2 hours and for 135 also coming 2 hours  while I have to display hours and minutes both

```
 let time=135
var Hours = Math.floor(time /60);

<View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                              <SmallText text={`Time Remaining is ${Hours} Hours`} textColor='green' style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}/>
                            </View>
```

// Thanks

Comment: this has nothing to do with react.

Comment: could you please tell me how i can convert in houres and minutes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert minutes to hours/minutes and add various time values together using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687723/how-to-convert-minutes-to-hours-minutes-and-add-various-time-values-together-usi)

Comment: Just use `time % 60` to get the remaining minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not calculating `minutes` here you need to calculate them

```js
let time=135
var Hours = Math.floor(time /60)
var minutes = time % 60

console.log(Hours)
console.log(minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same but if you have to do this inline in a react component, maybe you prefer this way:

```js
<span>`${Math.floor(min / 60)}:${min % 60}`</span>
```